# How to count new users in last month in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to know how many new users we have last month, and how many of them have turned into buyers while I can not figure it out smoothly.the following is what I coded.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(PRODUCT_ID)) 
FROM ORDER_TABLE AS O  
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_TABLE AS C
   ON O.CUSTOMER_ID=C.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,ORDER_DATE,GETDATE())<=1
```

And there is another question which has confused me a lot: Which category have the highest YEAR BY YEAR growth in terms of revenue in 2016?

Comment: sample data (as formated text) and expected result will be helpful

Comment: `GETDATE()` - doesn't look like MySQL

Comment: I see nothing in the question that tells me how a new customer turns into a buyer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because I have no idea about how to put last month in it so I put what I searched in website

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier I am little confused about this question...

Comment: What's a **user** under your business rules? What makes a user into a **new user** under those rules? When you say **last month** do you mean the calendar month most recently ended (in mid-August 2017 that would be July 2017)?  Please [eidt] your question to clarify these points.

Comment: You should be having a condition on how user becomes buyer and on what basis you will count new users of the last month. That also matters. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @O.Jones That's all what instructor gave me , I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Then you should be asking to your instructor about those conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it...

```
SELECT COUNT(Customer_ID)
FROM Customer_Table
WHERE Customer_ID IN (
        SELECT Customer_ID
        FROM Order_Table
        )
    AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, First_Visit, GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Comment: and how many of them have turned into buyers?Do you know how to code it?thanks

Comment: I can suggest you to make a column to maintain the buyer issue @Jeff Hoffman. If the user becomes buyer in any condition, then make that column value '**Buyer**'.

Comment: there is a another question could you help me to figure it out/

Comment: You have '**Order_Amount**' column in your database table specifically in `Order_Table`. Just do a sum on yearly basis (Of course! With a group by `Category`) and see what happens. There are few inner joins - Keep that in mind.

Comment: And why you choose first_visit?I'm a little confused about it

Comment: @AT-2017 Thanks for you remind,I will keep trying it!

Comment: New users should be counted from day 1 and I believe, that's to track the first visit of that particular user. That's why `First_Visit` is used in the query though I didn't answer that.

Comment: @JeffHoffman I chose ``first_visit`` because you wanted how many new users (signed up in the last 30 days) placed an order.  However, I'm making an assumption that ``First_Visit`` is when they sign up.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing ...

This gives a list of the new users last month.

```
 SELECT Customer_ID, Country, Gender
   FROM Customer_Table
  WHERE First_Visit >= (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND First_Visit < (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

That date range, given that today is `2017-08-14`, looks like this after all the date arithmetic. That means "the calendar month immediately preceding this day."

```
  WHERE First_Visit >= '2017-07-01'
    AND First_Visit <  '2017-08-01'
```

The Number of new visitors last month is a simple summary of that query.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Customer_Table
  WHERE First_Visit >= (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND First_Visit < (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1
```

Now, to elaborate a bit. How do we tell if a new user has purchased anything? We look in the order table. Something like this will do it.

```
 SELECT C.Customer_ID, SUM(O.Order_Amount) Total_Order_Amount
   FROM Customer_Table C
   LEFT JOIN Order_Table O ON C.Customer_ID = O.Customeer_ID
  WHERE First_Visit >= (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND First_Visit < (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 GROUP BY C.Customer_ID
```

This gives you a list of new customers, with a column showing how much each has ordered. So a `NULL` or `0` in the Total_Order_Amount column means a new customer who has never ordered anything.

**Pro tip:**

Incomplete and vague requirements are definitely part of stupid professor tricks. But they are also part of the world of information technology. Often a big part of a assignment, or a contract, or a project, is taking ridiculously vague requirements like the ones you've been given and refining them into something useful.

Comment: that should be a really excellent answer, I am really appreciated it!Let me ask me instructor later

Comment: could you have me to solve another question which I just updated? If you have time.

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question in each SO question posting. It looks like you need to ensure your professor has given you enough information about this kind of work to take it on.